# Storing a Hex Dump inside an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, hexdump

I am trying to create a PFS De-compressor using the C Language. For this Project, I need to analyse the Archive's Hex dump from which I will get the Files Offsets, names and Sizes.

Do you think it is good practice to store a Hex dump in a char array, and will I be able to convert Hex to Characters?

Thank you,
Andrew Borg

Comment: By "storing a hex dump" do you mean storing it in its ASCII format? Why wouldn't you just store the data in binary? I would assume it would be easier to analyze in binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"will I be able to convert Hex to Characters?"*

Yes. After your program reads in the literal characters that represent Hex digits -- for example, '5' and 'A', the program can turn that into the hex value 0x5a, which is decimal 90, and then print that value out as a character (which prints as "Z").
Pretty much every other conceivable way of converting characters to hex and vice versa is pretty easy in C.

[How to correctly convert a Hex String to Byte Array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267803/how-to-correctly-convert-a-hex-string-to-byte-array-in-c)
[Printing char buffer in hex array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275258/printing-char-buffer-in-hex-array)
[Convert array of bytes to hexadecimal string in plain old C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081422/convert-array-of-bytes-to-hexadecimal-string-in-plain-old-c)

I am not clear on what you are asking in the rest of your question.
Are you asking:

*"I have this binary PFS file; can I write a C program that, when the program is run, reads that file into RAM, and if so, is a char array (char[]) a good container?"*

Yes. When C programs read raw binary file data into memory, they typically store that data into a char array, *and* they keep track of the length separately (because, unlike char arrays that represent C strings, your binary data is likely to have the occasional zero byte).
You may want to look at the standard memory library functions ([memcmp()](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Code/Standard_C_Library/Functions/memcmp), [memchr()](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Code/Standard_C_Library/Functions/memchr), etc. )

*"I have an ASCII text file that is a hex dump of a PFS file; can I write a C program that, when the program is run, reads that ASCII text file into RAM, and if so, is a char array (char[]) a good container?"*

Yes. When C programs read text files into memory, they typically store that data in a char array. You don't need to keep track of the length separately, because ASCII text files never include a zero byte, so the normal end-of-string zero byte works normally.
You may want to look at the standard string library functions ( [strchr()](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Code/Standard_C_Library/Functions/strchr), [strstr()](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Code/Standard_C_Library/Functions/strstr), etc.).

*"I have this PFS file; can I write a C program that, before the program is ever run, the complete contents of that file are embedded into the executable code of my program?"*

In principle, yes, you could convert a raw binary file into a text file full of hex digits that you can include in your source code.

This is rarely done, and is a bigger hassle than simply loading the program in at run time,
but occasionally people do it when they want a single self-contained executable:

- [How to embed a file into an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288279/how-to-embed-a-file-into-an-executable)
- https://gist.github.com/valenok/4714740
- http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/352381/how-to-define-hex-character-array-in-c
- http://www.massmind.org/techref/datafile/charset/extractor/charset_extractor.htm
- [How to embed a file into an executable file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785214/how-to-embed-a-file-into-an-executable-file)
- [Embedding resources in executable using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-exe-using-gcc)
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967

p.s.:
Is your PFS file from an Amiga or a Playstation or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the Detailed Response. No sir, the PFS is from a Belkin router Firmware.